# Changing the label of from2 from within the function of form1

Tags: c#

Ok, so I have Form1 calling Form2 in a way that allows me to access Form1's functions from Form2. Code Below...

Form1....

```
    private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmForm2 tempDialog = new frmForm2(this);
        tempDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2...

```
    private frmForm1 _parent;

    public frmForm2(frmForm1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parent = frm1;
    }

    private void btnDoFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parent.DoProcess();
    }
```

Now I have a new problem. I'm trying to update a status label of Form2, but the function that's processing the task at hand is in Form1. How can I change the label of Form2 from within the Function of Form1?

Comment: if you could explain the real problem you are trying to solve you might get much better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do so using delegate and event.**

1. Make an event in form1 using a delegate
2. On progress in form1's process trigger the event.
3. put a handler to the form1 event in form2.
4. Extract the progress from that eventargs implemented object in the handler.
5. Show it in the lable in form2

Comment: Thank you. I solved my answer without doing this by putting everything in the same class, but I left this open because I wanted to learn how to do it in case I needed it later. Thank you for the learning experience. I can't believe its so much harder than it was in VB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mess... form1 displays form2 which calls a method on form1 which updates the contents form2?  Your question itself is easy (move the tempDialog variable to the form1 class instead of within this method - then you can use this during DoProcess to tweak whatever controls you want) but there is a serious maintainability problem here that you should step back and try to address.

Comment: I actually took the content from form2 and made form1 a multitab form, solving my maintainability issue. I only left this question open this was something I could do easily in VB and it hard to the point of not even having a simple answer in C#. My problem is fixed, now I'm just here to learn. Thank you though. I also realized it didn't make much sense too call back and forth. Now I just really wanna know how to change a label in another form.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access frm2.lbl from frm1 then frm2.lbl must be public, this can be changed in the properties window of the label on Form2. (under modifiers I think)

```
private void btnDoFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _parent.DoProcess();
}
```

(in form1)

```
public void DoProcess();
{
    tempDialog.lable.Text = "hope this works";
}
```